# Bringing data from one row into multiple rows using informatica

Tags: input, output, informatica

I have data where the `First name` , `last name` and the `company of the employee` are given along with the company's acquisitions and child companies all in the same row.
I want that across each first and last name each child company should be mapped one by one using informatica. 
The data is some what like this-

**INPUT**

```
First_name    Last_Name     Company      Child Company-1   ChildCompany-2
Jacki          Hatfield     Johnson   ALZA Corporation   ALZA Development
```

**output 1**

```
First_name    Last_Name   Child Company-1
Jacki          Hatfield    ALZA Corporation
```

**Output-2**

```
   First_name     Last_Name   Child Company-1
    Jacki          Hatfield    ALZA Development
```

Answer (score 2):

`Normalizer transformation` should help you. Here's an overview and an example: https://marketplace.informatica.com/solutions/mapping_transform_one_record_to_many